# Функция, возвращающая тип класса в котором она находится

Tags: typescript, шаблоны-проектирования, реализация

#### Описание

То, что я ищу очень похож на паттерн фабрика, но не одно и тоже. Есть вот такая конструкция:

```ts
class SettingsProgenitor {
    static import<T extends SettingsProgenitor>(source: any): T {
        throw new ReferenceError(`Not implemented function`);
    }
}
```

Сразу скажу почему класс, а не интерфейс: интерфейс не поддерживает статические члены.

Теперь мне надо, чтобы **любой другой класс, который наследует `SettingsProgenitor` имела статическую функцию `import`, которая вернет значение того же типа, в котором эта функция находится**. То есть:

```ts
class A extends SettingsProgenitor {
    static override import(source: any): A {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B extends SettingsProgenitor {
    static override import(source: any): B {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Пример, описанный сверху не работает, поскольку классы считаются не реализоваными. А если реализовать вот так:

```ts
class A extends SettingsProgenitor {
    static import<T extends SettingsProgenitor>(source: any): T {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B extends SettingsProgenitor {
    static import<T extends SettingsProgenitor>(source: any): T {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

...то ошибка `Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

#### Вопрос

Как эту проблему можно решить? Я попробовал все варианты которые предлагали ответы SO и ChatGPT - не помогло.